# How can I test a popover from chakra-ui

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, chakra-ui, react-testing

I need to test a popover from chakra-ui in a React App.
I tried with this. But It does not find the popover. If I try by text, then I cannot assert if it is visible.

```js
  it('show a popover when hover terms and conditions', () => {
    render(<SummaryForm />);
    const link = screen.getByText(/terms and conditions/i);

    const popover = screen.getByRole('dialog');

    expect(popover.parentNode).not.toBeVisible();

    userEvent.click(link);

    expect(popover.parentNode).toBeVisible();
  });
```

Comment: I also tried in the expect without `parentNode`

Comment: Show the code under test.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hidden option of the [API](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole#api):

> const popover = screen.getByRole('dialog', {hidden: true})

ChakraUI renders a wrapper div around the section that has the *dialog* role. You can see this by using *[screen.debug()](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#screendebug)* if you are using the testing-library. Notice the wrapper controls the visibility of said section, which starts as *hidden*, with styling elements and aria tags.

Using the *hidden* option allows you to look amognst the elements that aren't visible in the accessibility tree.

Since you want to test the popover, you should know there are some [issues with modifying and checking the visibility](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/209) of the popover when using jest-dom.

Answer (score 0):

The chakra Modal applies a `transform` style to toggle its visibility. `toBeVisible` only checks a limited set of style attributes - `transform` is not one of them - so you might have to check for those instead, for example:

For invisibility:

`expect(screen.getByRole('dialog')).toHaveStyle('transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0.18967%) translateZ(0);')`

Answer (score -1):

try `toBeInTheDocument()` or `toMatchSnapshot()`

Comment: The thing is that `const popover = screen.getByRole('dialog');` this does not find anything

Comment: This is not the solution because by default Chakra renders PopoverContent to the DOM even when it's not visible. One must test for visibility.